# I want to design an ANDROID app which sets user mobile number by taking input from them and after that it always shows next activity using service?

Tags: android

I want to design an ANDROID app which sets user mobile number by taking input from them and after that it always shows next activity using service each time when user opens the app but not that setting number activity.Please suggest me the method to do that..

Comment: Can you explain us what is your approach ?

Comment: You need to implement sharedPrefrences  open your number activity once get number from user and save it in sharedprefrence, and check every nect time with sharedpref boolean if number is stored then bypass number activity else show number activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
       if(sharedPref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true)){
            Intent startWelcomeScreen = new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
            startActivity(startWelcomeScreen);
            finish();
            Intent startWelcomeScreen = new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
            startActivity(startWelcomeScreen);
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

MainActivity.java

If your app is executing for the first time, then it is redirected to Welcome screen. Notice the finish() call in the Main Activity. It is important, otherwise the back button will take you to the mainActivity, which is of course not what you want.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
        editor.commit();
```

Welcome.java

You can also use,

```
editor.apply();
```

It does the job asynchronously, I suppose.